# Numba Signature for jitted function as argument

Tags: python, signature, jit, numba

I've looked in the numba documentation, but couldn't find anything.

I have a function to jit that takes a jitted_function as argument. I want to make eager compilation by adding a signature, just like:

```
@jit(float64('jit_func.type', int32, int32...))
```

'jitted_func.type' should be the "function type"

when I do:

```
type(jitted_func)
```

I get a CPUDispatcher object

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I am also looking for a solution to this. Unfortunately, @Carbon's suggestion does not work, because the type returned by `numba.typeof` for a function `bar` is different to the type of a function `baz`, even if the signatures of `bar` and `baz` are the same.

Example:

```py
import numba 

@numba.jit(
    numba.int32(numba.int32),
    nopython=True,
    nogil=True,
)
def bar(a):

    return 2 * a

@numba.jit(
    numba.int32(numba.int32),
    nopython=True,
    nogil=True,
)
def baz(a):

    return 3 * a

@numba.jit(
    numba.int32(numba.typeof(bar), numba.int32),
    nopython=True,
    nogil=True,
)
def foo(fn, a):

    return fn(a)
```

`foo(bar, 2)` returns 4

`foo(baz, 2)` returns the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_numba.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(foo(baz, 2))
  File "<snip>\Python38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 656, in _explain_matching_error
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) type(CPUDispatcher(<function baz at 0x000001DFA8C2D1F0>)), int64
```

The only workaround I've found is to omit the the function signature for `foo` entirely, and let numba figure it out. I don't know what negative consequences that has (if any) it may get your code running.

Example:

```py
import numba 

@numba.jit(
    numba.int32(numba.int32),
    nopython=True,
    nogil=True,
)
def bar(a):

    return 2 * a

@numba.jit(
    numba.int32(numba.int32),
    nopython=True,
    nogil=True,
)
def baz(a):

    return 3 * a

@numba.jit(
    nopython=True,
    nogil=True,
)
def foo(fn, a):

    return fn(a)
```

`foo(bar, 2)` returns 4

`foo(baz, 2)` returns 6

Comment: can you not write a wrapper function that takes in `fn` as an argument, determines the `numba.typeof` and feed into `foo`? This way, the type of can be determined dynamically

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not sure how to generate the signature you're looking for de novo, but if you have a sample of the compiled function with the signature you're going for, you can use `numba.typeof(...)` to get the intended signature, consider, eg:

```
import numba

@numba.njit(numba.int32(numba.int32))
def x(a):
    return a+1

@numba.njit(numba.int32(numba.typeof(x), numba.int32))
def y(fn,a):
    return fn(a)
    
print(y(x,3))
```

This is eager compiling, I checked. If you want to mess with this further, the right place to start is `numba.core.types.functions`, and the `Dispatcher` type is handled specially in compilation, see `numba.core.typing.context.BaseContext`'s `._resolve_user_function_type`.